# Integrating a Java Jar File (jTDS) into a Mac OSX App

Tags: java, macos, jdbc, jar

I have recently downloaded the jTDS driver from SourceForge. I tested it with Squirrel, and it works like a champ! However, I want to integrate it with the Mac OS X app that I am developing (I'm running Mac OS X with Xcode 4.3). I have not found any documentation or tutorials anywhere that can show me how to integrate the driver with my app. Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow any tutorial on creating JDBC connections and use the jTDS driver:

```
Connection conn = null;
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbHost, dbUser, dbPass);
```